# Assign observation level values by grouping variable

Tags: r

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have the below data frame

```
> df <- data.frame(
  id        = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5), 
  time      = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6), 
  mortality = c(NA,1,0,0,0,0,NA,0,0,0,0,1,NA,0,0,0,0,0,NA,0,0,1,0,0,NA,0,1,0,0,0)
)
> head(df)
   id time mortality
1   1    1        NA
2   1    2         1
3   1    3         0
4   1    4         0
5   1    5         0
6   1    6         0
```

`df$id` represents individuals measured at six points in time throughout a survival trail. At the start of the trial all individuals are alive and they subsequently die or remain alive. `df$mortality` represents within which time period that the individual died, for example individual 1 died in time period 2.

I would like to create a new variable indicating what I have called cumulative survival. This would indicate if the individual had died in the current time period or any of the previous time periods. How would I code this?

I have tried a number of different ways using `ifelse()` statements and dplyr `group_by()` without success.

Below is what the new data frame should look like. Thanks

```
> df
   id time mortality cum.survival
1   1    1        NA            0
2   1    2         1            1
3   1    3         0            1
4   1    4         0            1
5   1    5         0            1
6   1    6         0            1
7   2    1        NA            0
8   2    2         0            0
9   2    3         0            0
10  2    4         0            0
11  2    5         0            0
12  2    6         1            1
13  3    1        NA            0
14  3    2         0            0
15  3    3         0            0
16  3    4         0            0
17  3    5         0            0
18  3    6         0            0
19  4    1        NA            0
20  4    2         0            0
21  4    3         0            0
22  4    4         1            1
23  4    5         0            1
24  4    6         0            1
25  5    1        NA            0
26  5    2         0            0
27  5    3         1            1
28  5    4         0            1
29  5    5         0            1
30  5    6         0            1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the person will die only once, we can also use `cumsum`.

First replacing `NA` in mortality to 0 in `cum.survival`.

```
df <- transform(df, cum.survival = replace(mortality, is.na(mortality), 0))
```

We can then use base R :

```
df$cum.survival <- with(df, ave(cum.survival, id, FUN = cumsum))
```

`dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(cum.survival = cumsum(cum.survival))
```

Or `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, cum.survival := cumsum(cum.survival), id]
```

---

Another option is to match the row index in the group to the index where 1 is present.

We can use `which.max` :

```
df %>%  
  group_by(id) %>%  
  mutate(cum.survival = +(row_number() >= which.max(mortality)))
```

OR `match` :

```
df %>%  
  group_by(id) %>%  
  mutate(cum.survival = +(row_number() >= match(1, mortality)))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `by`:

```
df$cum.survival <- unlist(by(df$mortality, df$id, function(x) cummax(replace(x, is.na(x), 0L))))
```

or `ave`:

```
df$cum.survival <- ave(df$mortality, df$id, FUN=function(x) cummax(replace(x, is.na(x), 0L)))
```

or `tapply`:

```
df$cum.survival <- unlist(tapply(df$mortality, df$id, FUN=function(x) cummax(replace(x, is.na(x), 0L))))
```